# Why are all the iterations run at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JaQmd/) simulating my problem relating to this code:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
   var i;
   for (i = 1; i < 4; ++i) {
      $('#img' + i).fadeIn("slow").delay(1000);
      $('#img' + i).fadeOut("slow");
   }
});
```

I was expecting the `#img1` element to fade in and then for the execution to stop for 1 second and then fade out, then start over for the `#img2` element etc.

Comment: Why would you expect that? fadeIn is a synchronous call so it doesn't necessarily wait for it to complete.

Comment: @user814628, I think you meant to say "an asynchronous call", rather than "a synchronous call"

Comment: @user814628: Perhaps because the user genuinely didn't know that `.fadeIn` or any other effects functions in jQuery are asynchronous. Asynchronous execution is common in JavaScript, especially in modern JS frameworks, but everyone has to learn about it for the first time at some point. This is a good question that is applicable not only to animation effects in jQuery, but also for understanding AJAX and things like Backbone.js model fetching (which is really an abstraction of AJAX as well, but never mind that). Don't berate the user for not knowing; instead, provide an answer and teach :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason the animations appear to run at the same time is that jQuery's animations are all performed asynchronously. So what your code is doing is basically starting all of the animations, and then your browser handles the actual animations nearly simultaneously.

jQuery's animation functions do support the use of callbacks which are called after the animation is finished, however. By making sure that the later animations happen in this callback, we can force the animations to execute in sequence.

Here's one way you could implement your requirements ([jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/9zrpZ/)):

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    var i;
    var $elems = [];
    for (i = 1; i < 4; ++i) {
        $elems.push($('#img' + i));
    }

    var animate = function () {
        var $elem;
        if ($elems.length) {
            $elem = $elems.shift();
            $elem.fadeIn("slow").delay(1000).fadeOut("slow", animate);
        }
        // if the $elems has been cleared out, we're done and this function won't be requeued
    };

    animate();
});
```

Note that I'm queuing up another call to `animate()` as the callback for `.fadeOut`. The function will then re-execute, but the state of the `$elems` array will be mutated across each function call so that each element has its animations executed once, in order. When the array is cleared out, the function will run only once more to verify that the elements have all been animated, and in that case it will return without re-queuing itself.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

We unable to use **fadeIn()** delay inside for loop.

instead we can use **setInterval()**.

Please try following code.

```
var i;
var timeMgt;

$('#button').click(function(){
   i = 1;
   timeMgt = setInterval(ChangeImage,1000);
});

function ChangeImage()
{
    if(i<4)
    {
        $('#img' + i).fadeIn("slow").delay(1000);
        $('#img' + i).fadeOut("slow");
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
         window.clearInterval(timeMgt);
         return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why use a string argument to setInterval? Why not just pass the function name?

Comment: because we need to maintain 1 sec time interval for each image change. ChangeImage() function will call each 1 sec.

Comment: @suresh.g: You can *and should* use an actual function object (either a function name or an anonymous function) as an argument to `setInterval` or `setTimeout` because that way you avoid the pitfalls of running `eval` on a string (which, besides being a security risk, is also slower). Using a function object in no way impacts the ability of `setInterval` to maintain its interval. The other problem with this answer is that `ChangeImage` will continue to run even after all of the images have been animated (in each later case doing a comparison and returning), which is a waste of resources.

Comment: All you'd have to do is write the interval call like this: `setInterval(ChangeImage, 1000);`. You even use less characters. It's seriously win-win for everyone. Try it out on jsfiddle.

Comment: Awesome. If you can find a way to ensure that `clearInterval` is called when it's all done, I'll give you a +1 :-)

Answer (score 1):

You would want to utilize the callbacks in fadeIn and fadeOut function. Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/JaQmd/5/ .

The heart of the code is basically calling the callback with the new image number like so

```
var imageNumber = 0;

$('#button').click(function doAnimation() {
++imageNumber;
if(imageNumber <= 3){
   $("#img" + imageNumber).fadeIn('slow').delay(1000);
   $("#img" + imageNumber).fadeOut('slow', doAnimation);
  }
});​
```

Comment: You don't really need that global `imageNumber`, do you? :-( Otherwise a decent solution on the whole. (Then again, I suppose if this is run in `$(document).ready(function () { /* ... */ });` then you might be okay.)

Comment: That was for the sake of simplicity, I guess you can further encapsulate the variable if he wanted to or better yet pass it as an argument

Comment: Yeah, very true. I gave you +1 since this is already likely run inside an anonymous function (for `$(document).ready()`/`$()`).